# Button click event not firing after ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I am working in wordpress and my ajax function result showed one button whose html is mentioned below. Now I want to run a click event on that button but when I click it nothing happens. Below is the html and jquery code of the button I am using and kindly note that this button is shown as a result of an ajax operation. thanks !!

html

```
<input style="background-color:purple" id="readmore" type="button" value="Readmore!!" name="mybutton">
```

jquery

```
jQuery("#readmore").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("you clicked the button");
    jQuery("#bodytext").css("display","block");
});
```

Comment: have you enclosed this in ```$(document).ready(function(){///code here});```.

Comment: Since you have said `my ajax function result showed one button`, It looks like you are dealing with a dynamic element, so try `$(document).on('click', '#readmore', function(){//your stuff})`