# Button Click does not work after executing Ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a `readmore` button which is generated with Ajax and now I am using below code to execute a click event from this button, but nothing happens.

The button when clicked should unhide a div which is also dynamic and generated with Ajax. So this is all dynamic content I am dealing any ideas please. Thanks.

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#readmore', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("you clicked the button");
    jQuery("#bodytext").css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29863405/2025923

Comment: Tushar nobody is replying me there what should I do ... please suggest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements Read This.

Comment: I the code you posted also coming with the ajax request?

Comment: Btw, preventing default in this case does nothing.  The event has already bubbled all the way up to document in this case, since it's a delegated event.  Not the problem, but still...  Also see reference about why binding to document with delegates is bad  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824549/should-all-jquery-events-be-bound-to-document

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to make it work,

1. convert your button to hyperlink as `e.preventDefault` will prevent to click of button as it is its default behavior.
2. Remove the `e.preventDefault()` from your code.

Also make sure your have included any latest version of jquery. And write your code in [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) like,

```
$(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

Now, try to use any one option from the above.

Comment: Thanks Rohan let me try

Comment: I have removed e.preventDefault() but still no response from the page jQuery(document).on('click', "#readmore", function () {
    alert("you clicked the button");
    jQuery("#bodytext").css("display", "block");
});

Comment: let me try your other suggestion to convert it to a hyperlink and I will keep href value to empty

Comment: I'll give the same id=readmore'

Comment: Rohan both the solutions are not working

Comment: Now, try my updated answer

Comment: Rohan .... did I tell you that I am working in wordpress so using first option below is my jquery now jQuery(function($){
    $(document).on('click', "#readmore", function () {
  alert("you clicked the button");
    jQuery("#bodytext").css("display", "block");
 });
});

Comment: Don't use `$` if you are using then pass `jQuery` in self called function like `;(function(){/* your code here */})(jQuery);` otherwise try to use `jQuery` not `$`. And use `.show();` not `.css("display", "block");`

Comment: ok Thanks Rohan .... let me try

Comment: Rohan it did not work here is my code now jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click', "#readmore", function () {
  //e.preventDefault();
alert("you clicked the button");
    jQuery("#bodytext").show();
  });
});

Comment: Rohan ... just an idea that if jquery is not working so is there any hover functionality in css3 that can display the div on hovering on the readmore button.

Comment: will something like this work #bodytext {display:none;}

#readmore:hover #bodytext {display:block;}